# Switching to Vmware (player) without using a mouse

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vmware

I switch from a virtual machine to the host machine using `host` key then pressing <kbd>Alt-tab</kbd>, but when I switch back to the virtual machine, I am forced to click with a mouse to take the control back. Is there an option or a key that will let me switch to vm without having to use my mouse?

**Note**: I want to do this without VM grabbing my mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `cntrl-g` to capture keyboard input and `cntrl-a` to release the keyboard.

Comment: `ctrl-g` worked for me.